# Share current URL of UIWebview to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, share

so I want to share the current URL of my webview to facebook and twitter using the social framework in Xcode, can anyone tell me how to do this here is my code

```
- (IBAction)social:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *share = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pass on the news!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Post to Twitter", @"Post to Facebook", nil];

    [share showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (actionSheet.tag == 0) {
        if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Check out this article I found using the 'Pass'  iPhone app: "];
            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least one Twitter account setup and your device is using iOS6 or above!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[tweetSheet addURL:self.webView.request.URL];`

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems so simple now (: For anyone else who views this, this is hows its done for Facebook: [facebookSheet addURL:self.newsItemWebView.request.URL];